# Comma-separated values in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, csv

I have comma-separated values. I need a query to insert into SQL Server 2008 with different rows

> Bedford, Bloomfield, Broad Top, Colerain, Cumberland Valley, East Providence, East St. Clair, Harrison, Hopewell, Juniata, Kimmel, King,
>   Liberty, Lincoln, Londonderry, Mann, Monroe, Napier, Snake Spring,
>   Southampton, South Woodbury, Union, West Providence, West St. Clair,
>   Woodbury,Bedford, Coaldale, Everett, Hopewell, Hyndman, Manns Choice,
>   New Paris, Pleasantville, Rainsburg, St. Clairsville, Saxton,
>   Schellsburg, Woodbury,

Comment: in text file and stored it in table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
-- create a table to load the city names into
CREATE TABLE CitiesBulkLoad (CityName VARCHAR(100))

-- load the file into that staging table
BULK INSERT CitiesBulkLoad
FROM 'd:\commacities.txt'  -- replace with **YOUR** file name here!!
WITH
(
   FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
   ROWTERMINATOR = ','
)
GO

-- now you should have the entries in that staging table 
SELECT * FROM CitiesBulkLoad
```